# How to convert multiple rows into one row to get sum quantity

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I will need to combine multiple rows into one row to get the total of number. My table looks like this

```
Sublot_Number Lot_Number Qty Pallet_ID
------------- ---------- --- ---------
 S1             L1        1    P1
 S2             L2        1    P1
 S3             L3        3    P1
```

My result should looks like this

```
Sublot_Number  Lot_Num1 Lot_Num2 Lot_Num3 Qty_Sum Pallet_ID 
-------------  -------- -------- -------- ------- ---------
Random Number    L1       L2        L3      5        P1
```

I tried Pivot, but no luck. There may be more than 3 sublot will be used for the same Pallet, but I only will pick any three Sublot as Lot_Num1, Lot_Num2 and Lot_Num3

What would be a solution in this situation.

Comment: Please show what you tried - thats what we are here to help you with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation (or `pivot`), but the key is `row_number()`:

```
select rand(checksum(newid())) as sublot_number,
       pallet_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then lot_number end) as lot_num1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then lot_number end) as lot_num2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then lot_number end) as lot_num3,
       sum(qty)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by pallet_id order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by pallet_id;
```

If you want the sum of the quantity to only be for the three chosen lots, then add `where seqnum <= 3` to the outer query.

If you have some sort of prioritization -- such as the largest quantities -- then use that for the `order by`.